# Is there an easy way to share Android translations with an iOS project using LibGDX?

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, translation

I have an existing app written for Android with translations written specifically in the Android Translations Editor. Now I want to port my app to iOS.

Can I use the translations from Android in iOS?

Comment: Yes you can. Translation editor just creates new strings.xml files for each of languages you support. You can get these files and convert ios proper localization file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an option to handle localization via LibGDX and I decided to switch to using that.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Internationalization-and-Localization

I created a PHP script which converts my current Android translations to GDX translation files.